# How do you override the getter method for a Rails has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-one

I want to override/extend a Rails `has_one` association method so that it *always* returns an instance of the associated class. (If none already exists in the database, I want to create a new one and assign it to the parent instance.)

Ideally, I'd like to do this through the [built-in Rails association extension mechanism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions). However, I don't know the name of the "getter" method, and so I don't know what to override.

How do I override the association getter so that I can instantiate a new object when it's nil?

Comment: Overriding the has_one association macro may lead to tears. I go with 1) a migration that backfills missing data and 2) an observer with an after_create listener on the parent resource.

Comment: @TomL: I'll keep that in mind, but in this particular case, I'd like the actual instance (not just the data) to be available immediately when referenced (and not exist before).

Comment: You could handle it in the parent controller. In the `new` action do something like `@parent = Parent.new(:child => Child.new)`. In the `edit` action do `@parent = Parent.find(params[:id])` then `@parent.child = Child.new unless @parent.child.present?`. Something like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Rails 3, alias_method is not the preferred way to override association methods. Quoting from the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Overriding+generated+methods):

> ### Overriding generated methods
>
> Association methods are generated in a module that is included into the model class, which allows you to easily override with your own methods and call the original generated method with super. For example:
>
> ```
> class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
>   belongs_to :owner
>   belongs_to :old_owner
>   def owner=(new_owner)
>     self.old_owner = self.owner
>     super
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> If your model class is Project, the module is named Project::GeneratedFeatureMethods. The GeneratedFeatureMethods module is included in the model class immediately after the (anonymous) generated attributes methods module, meaning an association will override the methods for an attribute with the same name.

Comment: Ha ha, awesome! Randomly stumbling upon a friend's answer is like some kind of fate thing.

Answer (score 10):

You can alias the original method, then define a new one with the same name.

For example:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :associated_model

  alias :old_associated_model :associated_model

  def associated_model
    old_associated_model || AssociatedModel.new(my_model_id: id)
  end

end
```

I don't know if this is the canonical way to handle this situation, but it should work.

Comment: This will certainly work. I'm hoping to use the documented way to extend associations, but this is my fallback plan.